# Slow Datalab performance with lots of files on file system

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I have loaded a 3GB folder which has about 280k images and 5000 folders onto my datalab instance.  The datalab instance is now performing extremely slowly and is essentially unusable despite having more than enough capacity.  Could someone tell me why it is has slowed down to such a degree and how I could improve its speed?  It is currently maxed out on CPU even though there are no notebooks running.

```
PID   USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR   S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                         
1468  root  20   0 1755988   584136  20408 R 180.4  7.6  13:48.51 node
```

Comment: do you have access to the CLI for this instance?

Comment: I do, but I have found that trying to use pretty much any command on the cli for a data lab instance doesn't work - as in no command is recognised. I have tried the same commands on other compute instances and they have so Google may have locked down the datalab ones for some reason

Comment: are you able to use `top` to see what's hogging CPU?

Comment: thanks for the reply @eagle!  I have run top and will update the main post with the info

Comment: I have no idea what `node` is but you should investigate what that is

Comment: If you create a new datalab instance with same instance machine type(https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/machine-type), verify that it works alright, and then load this same 3GB folder you talk about, Does it happen again that you get this slowness behaviour?